# Smooth scroll not working, only after switching devices in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical navbar that can be opened and closed with .on(click, function) and .slideToggle() jQuery method on mobiles, but becomes horizontal on tablet and desktop. The navbar contains anchor elements that target elements within the same page. At the same time, I wanted to add a jQuery click() function with animate() method to create a smooth scroll when clicking on the  links. 
Here is my problem. I’m coding in JsBin and when I want so see the result in the Output view (default desktop size), the smooth scroll doesn’t work. Then I open the Chrome Developer Tools and switch to mobile view within device toolbar, the navbar toggles and the smooth scroll works perfectly. Switching back to desktop size, the smooth scroll suddenly works fine, too. Close the Chrome Dev Tools and the smooth scroll works perfectly. What can be the problem that results in smooth scroll not working on the first try?

First I tried to separate these two functions, this time the navbar couldn't be opened on mobile, but the smooth scroll worked fine on tablet and desktop. The second time I embedded the click() and animate() functions into the .on(click, function) responsible for the toggling, as you can see in the code. I experienced the same in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

```js
/* function to toggle the navigation bar
and make the scroll of links smooth */

function contentHide() {
  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav').slideToggle(300);

    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a').click(function() {
      $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
      }, 900);
      return false;
    });

  });
}

$(document).ready(contentHide);
```

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<navbar>
      <img class="logo" src="https://github.com/AnikoBorosova/Exercise-Flexbox-festival-website/blob/master/logo_placeholder.png?raw=true" alt="logo">
      <a class="toggle-button"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#C1">Home</a>
        <a href="#C2">About us</a>
        <a href="#C3">Program</a>
        <a href="#C4">Partners</a>
        <a href="#C5">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </navbar>
```

Here is the jsBin link to my whole code: https://jsbin.com/zoximog/24/edit?html,css,js
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use to nice scroll https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
It ll help you to soft scroll to specific page.